# AWS Lambda not resolving RDS address with internal IP after migrate from dotnetcore2.1 to dotnetcore3.1

Tags: .net-core, aws-lambda

After migrate my AWS Lambda from dotnetcore2.1 to dotnetcore3.1 it is resolving a RDS address with external IP.

Please any one have this experience?

It's better to use internal network address and avoid data transfer charges right?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you didn't also enable "publicly accessible" on the RDS instance recently?

Comment: External, or internal? The title says "internal", but the question text says "external". If it's internal, did check if a VPC config remained correct after the runtime update? Also, check for security groups issues

Comment: Perfect @Caldazar, when it upgraded it lost the VCP config. My serverless.template didn't have the "VpcConfig". Adding it solved my problem. Thank you very much!